# How can I find the value of k<sub>t+1</sub> for periods t=1...50?

Tags: python

I know that:
k<sub>t+1</sub>= (1−δ)k<sub>t</sub> + s * k<sup>θ</sup><sub>t</sub>
s=0.08, δ=0.3, θ= 0.35, k<sub>0</sub>=2.5

I wrote this:

```
(δ,s,θ) = (0.08,0.3,0.35)
k=2.5
K = (1-δ)*k+s*k**θ
print (K)
```

I want to calculate the value of k for periods 1,...,50
Of course, the result of my code is only for k<sub>1</sub>.
Can you help me understand how I can find the values up to k<sub>50</sub>?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Research what loops are (for and while).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate it with a simple loop like this:

```
δ, s, θ = 0.08, 0.3, 0.35
k = [2.5]
for _ in range(50):
    k.append((1-δ)*k[-1]+s*k[-1]**θ)
print(k)
```